# Tabbed Form in Ant Design Not Possible

Tags: antd

Tabbed Form doesn't seem possible in AntDesign v4

Blockers

1. On Submit only current active tab form values comes
2. If i have to generate tabs dynamically like English, French, Italian, i cannot initialize Form as tab loop will come inside of  component

Answer (score 6):

You can use the **forceRender** props on `<TabPane>` :

```
<TabPane tab="Tab1" key="1" forceRender>
```

[<TabPane>](https://ant.design/components/tabs/#Tabs.TabPane) component API on Ant Design doc :

> forceRender : Forced render of content in tabs, not lazy render after clicking on tabs.
> Boolean | Default `false`

Comment: forceRender: Forced render of content in tabs, not lazy render after clicking on tabs

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previous answer, you can pass "forceRender" as a field to your tabs object:

```
const items: TabProps['items'] = [
    {
        key: 'some-key',
        label: 'some-label',
        forceRender: true,
        children: (/*your tab content here*/)
    }, 
    /*...*/
]


<Tabs defaultActiveKey={'some-key'} items={items} />
```